# I am unable to Playback my CodeduiTest

Tags: playback

I am new to CodedUI, I am using VSTS 2012. Here I am able to record a script on IE9 but I am unable to play back the script. while play back it is giving an error says Unable to find Control. even I put wait and waitforcontrolready etc...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exception that is thrown you can use other click methods if you are sure the control is there. Loading may or maynot be the cause, thus waits may or maynot do anything. Example below, you can do custom clicks since each exception throw are caused by different reasons:

```
try{
            WaitForControl(uiControl);
            Mouse.Click(uiControl);                
        }
        catch (FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException e)
        {

            WaitForControl(uiControl);
            Mouse.Click(new Point(uiControl.Left + (uiControl.Width / 2), uiControl.Top + (uiControl.Height / 2)));
        }
        catch (FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException e)
        {

            WaitForControl(uiControl);
            Mouse.Click(new Point(uiControl.Left + (uiControl.Width / 2), uiControl.Top + (uiControl.Height / 2)));
        }
        catch (PlaybackFailureException e)
        {

            WaitForControl(uiControl);
            Mouse.Click(new Point(uiControl.Left + (uiControl.Width / 2), uiControl.Top + (uiControl.Height / 2)));
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            WaitForControl(uiControl);
            Mouse.Click(uiControl, new Point(uiControl.Left + (uiControl.Width / 2), uiControl.Top + (uiControl.Height / 2)));
        }
```